# Es valido este truco para llamar al constructor de un objeto de forma explicita en c++

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion Calculadora con prescicion de muchos decimales, quiero reservar 2 mb memoria anticipadamente porque es suficiente para el funcionamiento de la misma.

```
uint8_t* calculator_memory = new uint8_t[2*1024*1024]{};
```

El problema surge al querer usar esa memoria para construir objetos de mis clases, lo que hago es usar `reinterpret_cast<myclass*>(void*)` para crear punteros en el medio de esa memoria, pero esos objetos tienen el inconveniente de no estar inicializados porque el constructor nunca se llama.

Por casualidad me topé con un truco para llamar al constructor y se trata de usar `new` pero pasándole un parametro extra quedando así

```
myclass* objeto = new(void*) myclass();
```

El parametro extra es una ubicacion existente para no asignar memoria nueva y de esa forma puedo **llamar al constructor** de mis clases. Este truco me parece muy hacker y es la primera vez que veo que el operador `new` tiene un argumento extra y es muy raro que otras preguntas aseguran que no existe forma llamar al constructor explicitamente y este codigo lo logra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> es muy raro que otras preguntas aseguran que no existe forma llamar al constructor explicitamente y este codigo lo logra

Existe otras formas de llamar al constructor:

```
myclass objeto;                   // Se invoca el constructor
myclass objeto = myclass();       // Se invoca el constructor
myclass * objeto = new myclass(); // Se invoca al constructor
```

La diferencia entre estos mecanismos y el que planteas es que el que tu has descubierto tiene su utilidad cuando estás diseñando un sistema de gestión de memoria propio... como es tu caso. Este tipo de soluciones eran bastante comunes hace bastantes años, cuando los equipos tenían muchos menos recursos disponibles y los algoritmos de gestión de memoria eran, ciertamente, mucho peores que los actuales.

Por otro lado te digo que en un sistema moderno no necesitas preocuparte por la memoria, no al menos si tu idea es reservar 2MB. Básicamente por dos motivos:

- Cualquier equipo que ejecute tu programa tendrá, como norma general, varios GB de RAM
- Si un equipo con varios GB de RAM se queda sin memoria, el propio sistema empezará a comportarse incorrectamente ... tu aplicación será lo de menos

Adicionalmente debes tener mucho cuidado al usar este nuevo mecanismo ya que no se va a hacer ningún chequeo por parte del sistema, es decir, si no calculas correctamente el espacio que va a ocupar cada objeto acabarás sobreescribiendo memoria.

Dicho esto, sí, puedes usar este mecanismo para tus propósitos. Sin embargo no creo que haya ninguna razón de peso que justifique su uso más allá de fines meramente académicos.